# How combine multiple projections into a single pass?

Tags: opengl, projections, opengl-es

We have a projector type display used in an automotive application, where a projector displays an application on the windshield.  Because the projector would normally warp a flat image, we have to counter this warping. The way we do this is:

1. Render our content to a framebuffer
2. Apply that frame buffer as a texture on a special mesh that counteracts the warping from the projector.

As we've found, the final stages of the rendering pipeline (rendering pixels to a framebuffer / and or screen) are often the biggest bottlenecks on embedded hardware.

Is there any potential method we could use to reduce steps 1 and 2 to a single pass?  Essentially going through multiple projections, but without using intermediate frame buffers?

Comment: Yes, you can render directly your content onto your special warped mesh. If you could upload somewhere a sample of code that reproduces the same setup, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: @wip, I don't have any code, I'm just thinking theoretically.  A lot of times in computer graphics the algorithm is used 1) setup framebuffer, 2) render content to framebuffer, 3) apply framebuffer as texture on a mesh 4) render the mesh to the back buffer.

I'm just wondering if there is a theoretical way to achieve the same results without using framebuffer.

Comment: Are you using OpenGL? Desktop? Use an image rather than a sampler. It prevents you from having to setup an fbo for the texture and mess with all that. Not sure if it would be better for you though.

Comment: Using opengl es 2.0.  What do you mean by "image"?